# python is crashed while using fast_executemany as TRUE with Sql Server

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc, executemany

I am trying to import data from SourceDB to TargetDB. There are only 15000 rows in the respective table and taking approx 20 min with fast_executemany as False

but when I set fast_executemany as true my python interpreter crashed at cursorTarget.executemany(SQL1, data)

```
def ImportFunction(TargetServer,TargetDB,TargetTable,SourceServer,SourceDB,SourceTable,SQL,TCID) :
connectionStringSource = 'DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};SERVER='+SourceServer+';DATABASE='+SourceDB+';Trusted_Connection=yes;'
connectionStringTarget = 'DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};SERVER='+TargetServer+';DATABASE='+TargetDB+';Trusted_Connection=yes;'
connectionSource = pyodbc.connect(connectionStringSource)
connectionTarget = pyodbc.connect(connectionStringTarget)
cursorSource = connectionSource.cursor()
cursorTarget = connectionTarget.cursor()   
cursorSource.execute(SQL)
rowspart = []
while True :
    itrcount = 1
    rowspart = cursorSource.fetchmany(100)
    if not rowspart :
        break
        #break while loop
    data = rowspart
    connectionSource1 = pyodbc.connect(connectionStringSource)
    cursorSource1 = connectionSource1.cursor()
    rest = cursorSource1.execute("SELECT * FROM "+SourceTable+" WHERE 1=0")
    columnList = [tuple[0] for tuple in rest.description]
    String = ','.join(str(e) for e in columnList)
    StringSQL = "?, " * (len(columnList)-1)
    StringSQL = StringSQL+"?"
    StringSQL = " ) VALUES("+StringSQL+ ")"
    SQL1 = "insert into " + TargetTable + " ( "+ String + StringSQL
    if len(rowspart) > 50 :
        cursorTarget.fast_executemany = True 
    else :
        cursorTarget.fast_executemany = False
    try:
        cursorTarget.executemany(SQL1, data)
    except Exception as e:
        print 'error: ' + str(e)
        #break
    itrcount = itrcount + 1
    del rowspart[:]
    cursorSource1.close()
    del cursorSource1
    connectionSource1.close()

connectionTarget.commit()
cursorSource.close()
del cursorSource
connectionSource.close()
cursorTarget.close()
del cursorTarget
connectionTarget.close()
```

Comment: Are you using the latest version of pyodbc (currently 4.0.26)? If not, then update to the latest version and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

That issue is still under investigation. In the meantime you might be able to proceed by using a newer ODBC driver like DRIVER=ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server, and
running pip install pyodbc==4.0.22 to use an earlier version of pyodbc.